# Notification not coming when time is set in PM

Tags: android, alarmmanager

I have a reminder in my application which will trigger a notification 15 mins before the schedule alarm. I am using 24hour format so When I am setting the alarm in morning the notification is coming, but when I tried to set my alarm after 12:00 say 13:30 the notification is not triggering.

Here is my AlarmManager :

```
public void saveChanges(Context context) {
        init(context);

        if (getReminderStatus) {
            Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
            //calendar.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK, workOutDays[i] + 1); //+1 because for android sunday is 1
            calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, getHours());
            Log.d("alarm","hours"+ String.valueOf(getHours()));
            calendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE,getMinutes());
            Log.d("alarm","minutes"+ String.valueOf(getMinutes()));
            alarmManager.cancel(pendingIntent);
            alarmManager.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, calendar.getTimeInMillis(), AlarmManager.INTERVAL_DAY, pendingIntent);
        }
    }
```

AlarmReceiver :

```
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        getDataFromSharedPrefrence();
        if(!isTodayRestDay() && getReminderStatus){
            NotificationFCM notificationFCM = FCMUtility.getFCM(getIntentData());
            FCMHelper.instance.displayFCM(notificationFCM,context);
        }
        //Toast.makeText(context,"show notification",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
```

I tried to debug also but the control is not coming to onReceive when alarm is set in PM.Do I have to make any specific changes to trigger the alarm when set in PM.

Answer (score 0):

`Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY` accept 24 HOUR formate So you should change 12 hour formate to 24 Hour Formate when passing it to calender .

```
 calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, hoursForDayin24hourFormate);
```

Comment: Then why you add `PM` in question ? There is no AM/PM in 24 Hours formate . Log your date/time with SimpleDateFormate .

Comment: sorry to confuse. Alarm is not triggering when I set the time say 13:00

Comment: If you AlarmManager code is working then i think there is no way AM PM can make any difference . You probably missing out something . Print the whole timeStamp in `(dd/MM/yyyy hh/mm a)` and check the date .